# How to check if 2 strings separated by delimiters have matching word

Tags: javascript

Trying to check if 2 strings have matching word return true.

```
let 1st_string = chin, kore, span;
let 2nd_string = chin eng kore zulu

1st_string.split(',').indexOf(2nd_string) > -1
```

I tried above code but always returns false. I need to return true as 2_nd string contains 2 matching words from 1st_string.

Comment: First JavaScript variable names should not start with a numeral and  1st_string and 2nd_string are not valid string it should be st_string = 'chin, kore, span'; the same for nd_string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the names and values of the variables you can do the following

```js
let first_string = 'chin, kore, span';
let second_string = 'chin eng kore zulu';
const array1 = first_string.split(',').map(string => string.trim());
const array2 = second_string.split(' ');

function exist(list1, list2) {
    for (const element of list1) {
        if (list2.includes(element)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

const result = exist(array1, array2);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your second string will also contain a comma in between the words if yes then it is easy to achieve.

you can split the string 1 and 2 with a comma as delimiter like this

```
let firstString = 1st_string.split(',');
let secondString = 2nd_string.split(',');
```

after doing you will get the `firstString` and `secondString` variable as array then you can iterate the first array and check for duplicate using includes methods

```
for (let i in firstString) {
    if(secondString.includes(firstString[i])){
        //you can do whatever you want after finding duplicate here;
    }
}
```

Comment: secondString delimiter is ' ' not comma. but thanks that works too!

Answer (score 1):

[`1st_string` is not a valid variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/what-characters-are-valid-for-javascript-variable-names)

split the first string and use [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to see if the second string has any of the words in the resulting array :

```js
let string_1 = 'chin, kore, span';
let string_2 = 'chin eng kore zulu';

const check = (str1, str2) => {
  return str1.split(',').some(word => str2.includes(word));
}

console.log(check(string_1, string_2))
```